# ILogger added via `AddLambdaLogger` logs everything as [Information]

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ilogger

I recently added logging to a AWS Lambda function and noticed something weird when I checked the logs.

Everything being logged via the logger was showing as `[Information]` even if the call was specifically to log as a `Warning` or `Error`.

Here is where I set up the logger:

```
serviceCollection.AddLogging(logging =>
{
    logging.AddLambdaLogger();
    logging.SetMinimumLevel(Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LogLevel.Information);
});
```

and it gets injected as an instance of `ILogger` as a constructor parameter like this:

```
ILogger<MyClass> logger
```

So when I call something like

```
_logger.LogWarning($"Oh no");
```

I would expect it to log that as `[Warning]` but in the logs it shows as `[Information]`

Comment: What's in your `appsettings.json`? Are you overriding the log level by any chance in a `logging` block? Which version of .NET Core are you on? We can then help troubleshoot the issue :)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary This is .Net6 and the only things in the `appsettings.json` are 2 environment variables

Comment: Do you have a minimal project you could push to Github or share that reproduces the problem? From the face of it, this shouldn't happen

Comment: Any update on this?